# "PickerCmp.html(13,71): Expected 0 arguments, but got 1" When i run IONIC BUILD --PROD

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I trying to build an pwa app with ionic, when i run "ionic build" everything works fine. But when i run "ionic build --prod" this error is returned:

ERROR in node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/picker/picker-component.d.ts.PickerCmp.html(13,71): Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/input/input.d.ts.TextInput.html(1,928): Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/input/input.d.ts.TextInput.html(1,961): Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Answer (score 1):

You should uninstall ionic-angular

```
npm uninstall ionic-angular
```

then replace all your import from ionic-angular to @ionic/angular

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall ionic-angular

then replace "@ionic/angular" in all the imports.

You may not find ViewController in "@ionic/angular" - So do not keep a dependency over it.

I have faced this problem in Angular 8 and using iOnic 4.

IT works fine with Angular 7 - without the change with same version of ionic version.

Check your ionic version using command-

> ionic info